# UDP and socket on responce to client

Tags: multithreading, sockets, networking, udp

I got the UDP communication up and running. 
In a simple striped down version the client is basically doing this: (Yes, there are a lot of ifs and error checking in the code and No, without a lot of definitions it will not work as is. But I am more on the conseptual here than actually code)

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
server_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
sendto(sock, "Hi", 3, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, server_length);
numRes = recvfrom(sock, (char *)buff, (int)sizeof(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, &server_length);
```

And the server is basically the same:

```
sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,length);
resBytes=recvfrom(sock,buff,(int)sizeof(buff),0,(struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen);
sendto(sock, "Test",5, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, fromlen);
```

This works. Both ends receive the data the other end sends.

Here is my problem: The server should be handling e lot of requests at the same time. I made a queue for the messages so that another thread could handle them, before I send them back to the client in yet another thread. When I do this I created a new socket for the sending, used the same "from" address that follows the message, but the client never receive it.

Is it correct to understand that replying on a UDP message has to be done with the same socket?

If I use the same socket for sending and receiving, what happens if I have three clients sending in messages, then after those are processed I will answer them in a random order. Will this work?

I can make a "server" on the client, but my guess is that any NAT would kill that idea fast.

What I try to attempt is more or less this:

```
sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
sock2=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,length);
resBytes=recvfrom(sock,buff,(int)sizeof(buff),0,(struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen);

sendto(sock2, "Test",5, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, fromlen);
```

If this kind of code should work, I will go back to my debugging, but right now it seems like this is not the case.

Edit:
Someone added "Multithreading" as a tag. Forget the multithread thing Its more to explain why I don't respond promptebly to the same request. I can have all the communication in one thread if thats whats needed. Sorry if this confuse people, but my main question here is: a) Can I send response down another socked without defining a "server" on the client. b) If not, how will it handle random order of reply on the same socked (IE Client A sends, Client B sends, answer to Client B, then to Client A)

Comment: Sockets cannot be shared by multiple threads. But hence UDP is a connectionless protocol, you can use different sockets to receive and send.

Comment: @user0042: "*Sockets cannot be shared by multiple threads.*" sure, they can. It's just a matter of how access is synchronised.

Comment: @alk Well, synchronization defeats the purpose of using separate threads a bit, no?

Comment: Well, ignore the thread question. I can put the sender and reciever in the same loop if needed. The main question here is: a) Can a responce be sent on another socked. b) What if I respond to several requests in random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for a single UDP socket to receive data from multiple sources and to send data to multiple peers, as long as the socket is not connected. This means if you explicitly or implicitly bind the socket and then use `sendto` and `recvfrom` (or `recv`) then you can use the same socket to send and receive data from multiple peers. But, if you first `connect` the socket then you will only be able to receive data from a socket which is bound to the connected ip:port, i.e. usually the same socket which received the data.

To test this you can use a simply Python server (would work the same with C). This server creates two sockets: `sock1` and `sock2`. It will receive a message on `sock1` and then send a message back using first `sock2` (the one which did not receive the original message) and then `sock1` (the one which received the original message):

```
from socket import *

sock1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)
sock2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)

sock1.bind(('127.0.0.1',9999))
data,addr = sock1.recvfrom(1024)
print("got '{}' from {}".format(data,addr))

sock2.sendto(b"send from sock2", addr)
sock1.sendto(b"send from sock1", addr)
```

As the peer we have a client which depending on the configuration uses a connected socket (i.e. `connect` + `send`) or an unconnected socket (i.e. no `connect` and `sendto`):

```
from socket import *

connected=False
sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP)
if connected:
    sock.connect(('127.0.0.1',9999))
    sock.send('send from connected client')
else:
    sock.sendto('send from unconnected client',('127.0.0.1',9999))
while True:
    data,addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print("got '{}' from {}".format(data,addr))
```

If you run the client with the connected socket (`connected=True`) you'll see that it will only get the message from `sock1` back, because `sock1` is (explicitly) bound to the ip:port the client is connected to and `sock2` is (implicitly) bound to some other address:

```
got 'send from sock1' from ('127.0.0.1', 9999)
```

If instead the client is using an unconnected socket (`connected=False`) then it will receive both the messages from `sock1` and `sock2`:

```
got 'send from sock2' from ('127.0.0.1', 44596)
got 'send from sock1' from ('127.0.0.1', 9999)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is answering my question. As far as I can see, I do the "not connected" one with sending back from two sockets. Then there must be something wrong with my code.

Comment: @AslakBerby: if you have a device doing NAT between client and server then it will usually create the a *state* consisting of ip,port from both sides of the connection and let only packets pass from the server which match this state. In this specific example: packets sent from sock1 will pass through the NAT device while packets sent from sock2 will be discarded since there is no matching state. This is also true for stateful firewalls even if they don't do NAT.

Comment: I was starting to realize that. As most homes today has some kind of NAT between them and internet, I must assure that it works with NAT and then go for a connected version. I moved all UDP code into the same class and using only one socket. I will just have to do some tests to see that I can connect with multiple clients.